# c# variables reset when code is moved from keydown event into a function - can anyone explain why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using a C# windows forms application in VS Express 2010. I'm playing around with some code for the purposes of learning. I have a form object, which I want to continually move in one direction with a key press - original code for this works fine.

In the process of trying to tidy it by moving the code for "movement" into a function, the code no longer works as before. Instead of my object moving from its current position in the direction selected, it now resets its position every time a key is pressed. I was wondering why this is happening, as the change I have made is absolutely minimal. Please see code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{          
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        direction = 4;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        direction = 2;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        direction = 3;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        direction = 1;
    }

    while (direction != 0)
    {

        Application.DoEvents();
        if (direction == 1)
        {
            X = X - 1;
        }
        else if (direction == 2)//up
        {
            Y = Y - 1;
        }
        else if (direction == 3)
        {
            X = X + 1;
        }
        else if (direction == 4)//down
        {
            Y = Y + 1;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        label1.Location = new Point(X, Y);
    }
}
```

when I move the while loop into a movement function, the variables X and Y are reset to 0 upon every key press. code for this looks as follows:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{          
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
  {
      direction = 4;
  }

  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
  {
      direction = 2;
  }

  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
  {
      direction = 3;
  }

  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
  {
      direction = 1;
  }

  movement(X, Y, direction);
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here but I don't understand why it's behaving differently. Thanks for any help :)

EDIT 1: The code for the movement function:

```
    movement(int X, int Y, int direction)
    {
        while (direction != 0)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (direction == 1)
            {
                X = X - 1;
            }
            else if (direction == 2)//up
            {
                Y = Y - 1;
            }
            else if (direction == 3)
            {
                X = X + 1;
            }
            else if (direction == 4)//down
            {
                Y = Y + 1;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            label1.Location = new Point(X, Y);

        }            
    }
```

Comment: Post your `movement` method. You are passing `X` and `Y` as parameters, but I guess these are class fields. You should not pass these as parameters. `movement()` already has access to those if it is a member method.

Comment: @mshsayem apparently even `direction` is a class field (as we can't see the declaration), so he could even call `movement()` without any parameter

Comment: @Rafalon Right.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` should *always* be viewed with suspicion. If you want something to happen on a ongoing basis (like your while loop) and for the UI to be interactive, it's usually an indication that that code belongs in a *timer* callback rather than an endless loop that's trying to run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `movement` method changes `X` and `Y` which were supplied as parameters. However, the parameters `X` and `Y` are passed 'by value', not 'by reference'.

If you want to make this work, you either have to use class variables, and remove the parameters in the method call, or use `ref`, which I will demonstrate:

```
movement(ref X, ref Y, direction);
```

And:

```
private void movement(ref int X, ref int Y, int direction)
{ }
```

Comment: If his `movement` method is nothing more than the `while` loop, then it doesn't do any change to `direction`, so passing it by ref is not going to solve the problem

Comment: My bad, it was `X` and `Y` obviously.

Comment: This was perfect, thanks! Knew it had to be something simple, I have some reading up to do on passing by reference. Seems like this might be similar to pointers in C, something I thought was pointless when I first learned about at uni but now I'm seeing I should have listened closer...

Comment: @ChristianT it is indeed similar to pointers in C except you don't have to use `->` or `*` or stuff like this to access members or value. It allows the called function/method to play with the object directly instead of with a copy of said object

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{          
    if      (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)  direction = 4;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)    direction = 2;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) direction = 3;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)  direction = 1;

    while (direction != 0)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();

        if      (direction == 1) X--;
        else if (direction == 2) Y--;
        else if (direction == 3) X++;
        else if (direction == 4) Y++;

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        label1.Location = new Point(X, Y);
    }
}
```

Could be rewritten :

```
private void SetDirection(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if      (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)  direction = 4;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)    direction = 2;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) direction = 3;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)  direction = 1;
}

private void ApplyMovement()
{
    while (direction != 0)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();

        if      (direction == 1) X--;
        else if (direction == 2) Y--;
        else if (direction == 3) X++;
        else if (direction == 4) Y++;

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        label1.Location = new Point(X, Y);
    }
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{          
    SetDirection(e);

    ApplyMovement();
}
```

You have to understand that the variables `X`, `Y`, and `direction` are class members, so they are accessible from anywhere in your class, and when you call `movement(X, Y, direction)` then `movement` plays with *copies* of those variables, so when you do `X = X + 1` inside your `movement` method, you are not actually changing the `X` value of your class, but only to the *copy* of it.
This means that the variables X and Y (i.e. class members) are not *reset* to 0 upon every key press. In fact ***they are never set to anything else***.

Note that you could also use `switch` statements instead of all those `if`s.

```
switch (direction)
{
    case 1: X--; break; // left
    case 2: Y--; break; // up
    case 3: X++; break; // right
    case 4: Y++; break; // down
}
```

Comment: was in the process of tidying my code but this has done it nicely, thankyou!

Comment: @ChristianT You're welcome, feel free to upvote useful answers (not mine specifically), and to mark the answer that solved your question the best as accepted (I've seen that you wrote *This was perfect* on Patrick Hofman's answer)